# Visual representation of numbers as results of multiplication, summation and power on a 2D plane, using vectors.

Tags: matrices, prime-numbers, vectors, visualization

I am interested in understanding a visual representation of results of operations between numbers, on a 2D plane.

I wonder if a visual representation on cartesian graph could be eventually "mapped" to operations that can be performed on matrices, using vectors.

So to coherently represent a visual representation of operations, as 1 + 1 , 1 x 1, 1 x 1 x 1 (1^3).

Consider the following images:

summation 
[image]

multiplication
[image]

power 
[image]

I interpreted that:

1. a summation **a** + **b** could be represented by a vector of length |a + b| , in the same direction : in the case of planar graph, 1+1 might be represented by a vector of length 2 along axes *x*.

This could be interpreted with a Cartesian graph as well.

(see FIG. 1)

2. a multiplication **a** x **b**  would be represented by a vector normal to a, b - thus, a vector along axes *z*

Though, on a Cartesian graph this would be represented by a cube -  a power, or with a bit of imagination, "a plane" times another "plane", and I figure axes are represented as normal to each other because they may "capture" the concept of vector multiplication.

3. on a Cartesian graph, a x b could be represented as the surface between axes *x, y* - as a square. But a plane may represent a cosine similarity concept between two vectors.

I figure a conceptual glitch is in one case one we use vectors and in the other planes and volumes. Although, in both we recur to augmenting a dimension when using multiplication.

I would like to know which visual representations may better represent the operations of summation, multiplication and power, on a 2D plane.
Visual representation of operations like : 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 and 2 x 2 should be equivalent.

I raise this question inspired by https://youtu.be/lRZ4aMaXPBI?t=542 :
having a formal visual language to represent what a resulting "number" is, it may be of help to understand concepts of numerability and concepts like factorisation in primes, and matrices decompositions.